# How to remove white space in text message in node.js?

Tags: node.js

we are sending booking confirmation message through SMS using node.js. If we use break tag it's displaying `<br />` along with message so we are using \n to give break after a particular line. But we are getting white space in the text message. How can we remove white space
Could anyone please help me.

```
otpMessages(otp, doctor_fullname, passwd, mobile_number) {
return `
  x has invited you to join Platform. 
  Please click on the following link to download and register. \n
  Your OTP is ${otp}. \n
  Download App: (app link) \n

  Thanks,
`;
},
```

Comment: Where is the extra whitespace you don't want?  At the beginning of each line?  Because **you** typed the whitespace -- when you indented the text inside your template literal.  You also provided an initial line break after the opening backtick.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it without any line break

```
otpMessages(otp, doctor_fullname, passwd, mobile_number) {
return `
  x has invited you to join Platform. 
  Please click on the following link to download and register.
  Your OTP is ${otp}.
  Download App: (link)

  Thanks,
`;
},
```

Comment: I suspect the indenting is the unwanted whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all extra indents from your string template, but the code would look ugly.

So I suggest to do it by concatenating strings.

Example:

```js
otpMessages(otp, doctor_fullname, passwd, mobile_number) {
  return [
    'x has invited you to join Platform. Please click on the following link to download and register.',
    `Your OTP is ${otp}.`,
    'Download App: (link)',
    'Thanks,'
  ].join('\n\n')
},
```

Result:

```
x has invited you to join Platform. Please click on the following link to download and register.

Your OTP is <otp>.

Download App: (link)

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings) approach, in case you still want to use it.

I think you may just be unfamiliar with how to control whitespace within your template literal.  Basically: *what you see is what you get*.  If you type whitespace such as indenting or a line break, it's there.  If you don't want it, then omit it.

e.g.:

```
technique1 = `Hello
World`;

technique2 = `Hello\nWorld`

alternate_technique = [
    'Hello',
    'World'
  ].join('\n');
```

It **will** mess with the overall indenting of your program though, in that everything after your first literal end-of-line will cause a disturbance in the apparent indentation of your program.

So if you indent your code you might get unintended/unwanted whitespace:

```
wrong = `Hello
         World`

which_is_the_same_as = `Hello\n         World`;
```

> If you really want to keep the code indenting, then consider a different
>   approach for writing your multi-line string, such as the [technique Ihor
>   suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57413459/1563833) where you use
>   an array and string join with `'\n'` to keep code indenting, but still add line breaks.

I'm not 100% sure where you want your line breaks, and if you're trying to insert extra (double-spaced) line breaks or what, but this outlines the basic concept for the solution.  But here I've demonstrated:

- how to remove line breaks (between `Platform.` and `Please`)
- how to add a single line break (after `register.` before `Your`)
- how to add double-line break vertical whitespace (after url, before `Thanks,`)
- how to remove initial line break (after opening backtick)
- how to remove final line break (before closing backtick)
- how to remove whitespace at beginnings of lines (do not indent)

```js
let otp = '12345';

function bad() {
  return `
    x has invited you to join Platform. 
    Please click on the following link to download and register. \n
    Your OTP is ${otp}. \n
    Download App: (link) \n

    Thanks,
  `;
}

function good() {
return `x has invited you to join Platform. Please click on the following link to download and register.
Your OTP is ${otp}.
Download App: (link)

Thanks,
`;
}

console.log(bad());
console.log(good());
```

---

As a matter of DevOps, I can say that in production code, I write large message templates like the one you've shown as *their own stand-alone text files*; and I use a build step that translates the literal text in the file into JavaScript.  I realize it doesn't directly allow for string interpolation using the technique you used, but there are plenty of ways of introducing templating, markdown, etc., or even use a string compiler that allows you to pass through the JavaScript template literal syntax directly to the compiled code (although this is dangerous and fragile, from a code and security perspective).

This also helps when you want to localize messages into different languages - you'll need to provide different templates for each language.  I do all my user-facing template text this way, such as for automatically generated emails, user-facing error messages etc.  It also allows for my technical writing team to modify user-facing text in a stand-alone file without having to modify (or be scared by) adjacent JavaScript code.